# how to show result from database tables in codeigniter?

Tags: mysql, join

I want to show data to the user that inserted by its admin.

It means, suppose `Admin_1` having 3 users:

```
(user_1, user_2, user_3)
```

and 5 customers:

```
(cust_1, cust_2, cust_3, cust_4, Cust_5)
```

all are in table `user`, and `Admin_1` having 4 products:

`(prod_1, prod_2, prod_3, prod_4)` in table product.

Same that Admin_2 having 4 users`(u_1, u_2, u_3, u_4)` & 3 customers `(c_1, c_2, c_3)` they also in table user, and product of `Admin_2` `(P_1, P_2, P_3)` in table product.

### Example data

**user table**

```
 id | user_name | admin_id | dept_id |
====|===========|==========|=========|
 1  | ABC(admin)|   ---    |  1      |
 2  | DEF(Test )|    1     |  4      |
 3  | PQR(HR   )|    1     |  2      |
 4  | UVW(admin)|   ---    |  1      |
 5  | XYZ(Sales)|    4     |  3      |
 6  | GHI(Cust )|    4     |  0      |
 7  | JKL(Test )|    1     |  4      |
 8  | MNO(HR   )|    4     |  2      |
 9  | STU(admin)|   ---    |  1      |
10  | VWX(Sales)|    9     |  3      |
```

**dept table**

```
 id | dept_name 
====|===========
 0  | Customer
 1  | Admin
 2  | HR
 3  | Sales
 4  | Tester
```

**product table**

```
 id | prod_name | admin_id |
====|===========|==========|
 1  | Prod_1    |   1      |
 2  | Prod_2    |   1      |
 3  | Prod_3    |   4      |
 4  | Prod_1    |   9      |
 5  | Prod_3    |   1      |
 6  | Prod_1    |   4      |
 7  | Prod_4    |   1      |
 8  | Prod_6    |   4      |
 9  | Prod_5    |   9      |
10  | Prod_5    |   1      |
```

My question is how to show the product list to `user_id == 2`, that inserted by its admin. i.e. `admin_id == 1`.

```
user_id == 2

 id | prod_name | admin_id |
====|===========|==========|
 1  | Prod_1    |   1      |
 2  | Prod_2    |   1      |
 5  | Prod_3    |   1      |
 7  | Prod_4    |   1      |
10  | Prod_5    |   1      |
```

sorry for table formatting, please help me if any one understand the question.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT p.* 
FROM
   product_table AS p
   INNER JOIN user_table AS u ON u.id=p.admin_id
WHERE u.id=2
```

Answer (score -1):

please give the table which relate users with products

Comment: I'm relating these two tables by using id_admin field from both tables.

Comment: select product.* from  product where admin_id=1